# Do search engines see URLs when the controller path is admin only?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, seo

I'm working on the SEO of my site and I have several urls for grant pages as such: `https://www.example.com/grant/@grant.name`

For some reason none of my grants are coming up in search results including SEO testers like screaming frog.  Anyone can see any grant page by gong to the url: `grant/@grant.name` but the index (`/grant`) is admin only.  Could this have anything to do with my grant pages not showing up for search engines?  If yes, would using shallow root help? so instead the url would be `https://www.example.com/@grant.name`  The index is a work in progress so I can't make it public yet otherwise this would be my first solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you link to these pages anywhere accessible to a search engine, so a web crawler can find it?

Have you considered setting up a sitemap?

Have you checked robots.txt? Just in case it's blocked (unlikely)

Sounds to me the webcrawlers haven't got to your pages, you can probably filter your access logs to see where they do go, but nothing you say leads me to believe they'll find your pages..

Comment: I have added a sitemap that has all the grant pages listed and the robot.txt is fine.  It's strange because I just built a new page /profile yesterday which is already showing up on screaming frog while the grant pages some built weeks ago aren't.

Comment: out of interest do these new links have an @ symbol?

Comment: no they are like grants/dean-witter-foundation-grant.  I use a slug field to set the url as the grant name.